# Touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 10.10, and I have an IBM ThinkPad T43 that the touchpad buttons don't work. For example I don't have a right click and the left click is on the right. button. Can someone help me to correct this problem. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the mouse options on System > Preferences > Mouse? There you can specify if you are left or right handed. You can also try looking for the Linux drivers for your touchpad, if they exist.